# Updating transform during transition causes transition to flicker on IE and MS edge

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, animation, microsoft-edge

Consider the following code (simplified):

**html:**

```
<button>move!</button>
<div/>
```

**js:**

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
var x = 0

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function () {
  x = x + 100
  div.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + x + 'px, 0,0)'
}
```

**css:**

```
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
```

Changing the transform property repeatedly, during a transition, will cause the div to flicker (towards previous start position) before transitioning towards the correct value.

This only seems to happen on MS browsers (tested on IE11 and MS Edge).

Also tested on Chrome, Safari, FF, which all work as expected.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/youridaamen/8pnLfmpt/12/

Related: [MS Edge CSS transform transition flickering on mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238701/ms-edge-css-transform-transition-flickering-on-mouse-move)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the transform style to marginLeft and it seems to work better (on IE).
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pnLfmpt/13/)

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')
var start = buttons[0]
var reset = buttons[1]
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
var x = 0

start.onclick = function () {
x+=100;
div.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
}

reset.onclick = function () {
x = 0
div.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
}
```

Comment: Works, but will not perform that well compared to transformations (recommended read: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)